# How to not repeat the activities and always continue from where I stand..?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm Creating a game so when i press start button starts from (A1.class) so if the user finished this task he will Intent to (Result activity) there is continue (next)button if he press goes to (A2.class so on...) what I want when the app is restarted and the user press start button continues from A2 or A3 and same thing for next button in the Result activity i dont want A1 appears (or A2 if he is at A3 task)

MainActivity

```
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //here I want to countiue the counting and not start from the first
            // let say i'm at A2 i want to go to A3
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , A1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

ResultActivity

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //here I want to intent to the new activity A3,A4 etc...
        }
    });
}
```

**Start button continue from where I was**

**next Button intent into the next Activity from where I'm**

Comment: you don't want to do this from your ResultActivity? `Intent intent = new Intent(ResultActivity.this , A2.class);
            startActivity(intent); finish();` don't forget to use `finish()` as will to prevent user's from going back to previous activities

Comment: when i start the app again i want to continue from i was  let  say (a6) if i answer a6 task i go to resultactivity then press the next button to go into a7 activity

Comment: if i close the app after a6 and reopen it i start from a7 ...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know your `Activities` (e.g. their names), you could store a `String` in your `SharedPref` whenever `onDestroy()` of activity is called (= user exits the App). This `String` would tell you which `Activity` it was, before it got destroyed.

On the App Launch (re-start), check your `SharedPrefs` and do a `switch` statement to determine which one of the `Activites` was the last. Please read first about `SharedPrefs`, so that I do not copy too much code - everything is well explained:

- [Reading and Saving items in SharedPrefs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

  ```
  start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          //here I want to countiue the counting and not start from the first
          // let say i'm at A2 i want to go to A3
          Intent intent;
          SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

      // Here I get the activityName, which was stored onDestroy();
      String activityName = sharedPref.getString("key", "defaultValue");

      switch(activityName) {
          case "A1":
              intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , A1.class);
              startActivity(intent);
          break;
          case "A2":
              intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , A2.class);
              startActivity(intent);
          break;
      }

  }});
  ```

Another approach for `NextActivity` could be that you define an Array of String with Activity names.

```
String[] activitiesArray = new String[numberOfActivites];
```

Now `onDestroy()` you save which activity was destroyed and you know the index of that `Activity` in your `array`, so you could also store the `Index` of the `Activity` within your array.

When you need your `NextActivity` to launch, just call retrieve the `Index` of the `Activity` and increment it by +1..this should give you the `NextActivity`.

Comment: I know about sharedPreference but what about next button in the result activity how it will know I'm on A6 to goes to A7

Comment: It should be the same. If you have info to which activity you want to go (because it is in SharedPrefs), so should next button know where to go, because you provide it the information. Otherwise check again how you implemented your next button, if this is not enough information for it.

Comment: @EasyE use `Extras` and pass a value to the result activity of what activity it came from

Comment: +1 for Roljhon  .. also dont forget that you as dev know the order of Activities you have.. so if you have information about X activity..then you know which is the X+1 and you could also create some table / ArrayMap to find value of X+1 (next activity, based on X being current).

Comment: can you check my edit  sharedpreference should i add that in every A1,A2 ,...?

Comment: Hm. But what does it help you if you know that Activity was executed? Do you save somewhere else which Activity it was? I would save a String of the name of Activity.. and then based on that call appropriate Intent. Maybe I do not understand your concept well enough.

Comment: I added another option that might help you get NextActivity.

Comment: So.. whenever your user exits the App, activity will call onDestroy() method. You can do some things in onDestroy() method. There I would store information which Activity is getting "Destroyed" (which Activity is the last that the user had opened, before he closed the App).

Comment: i'm trying to do something like this..
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.lotum.whatsinthefoto.us&hl=en

Comment: now when i clear the data of the app  and i press start button not going to any activity :O

Comment: thanks anyways i found a solution of course your solution is right too thanks again